# Rendering upscaled SVG with vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke on JS canvas in chrome results in border being too thick

Tags: google-chrome, svg, html5-canvas

I am trying to render a small SVG (`width="3.0202789" height="2.5201435"`) on a canvas.
SVG file was created by importing some CAD render result into Inkscape, removing all unnecessary parts and clipping to the content so it contains weird transforms.
All paths have `stroke-width` of `1px` and `vector-effect` set to `non-scaling-stroke`. As far as I understand SVG specs that shuould instruct the renderer to always keep stroke width at 1px in screen space units no matter of scale.
SVG is loaded into an  element then the the element's width and height are set to some sensible values.
It renders as intended in Firefox and using Node Canvas though in Chrome it looks like the ctx.drawImage method completely ignores the `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` instruction and computes stroke-width in viewbox units. The upscaled  element is rendered as intended though:

Rendering results:

1. [Firefox rendering (img on the left, canvas on the right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG3sp.jpg)
2. [Chrome rendering (img on the left, canvas on the right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwsOS.jpg)

JSFiddle with a minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/ucojz62n/

Chrome version used: Chromium 108.0.5359.124 (though the issue has been around for more than two years)

Firefox version used: 108.0 (though it worked great 2+ years ago as well)

Comment: upd: the problem exists in Safari as well likely due to common WebKit engine code. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucojz62n/1/

Comment: It's basically caused by https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6546 Firefox doesn't respect the HTML specs Regarding how to size the svg image when passed to drawImage, so they don't do the same thing with vector-effect. WebKit would be right here, even if they don't do what you want.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/1018487

Comment: Thank you, this info should help me to find a workaround :)